# how i can use custom shape use flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

[image]

how I can put any image inside a shape like this image I used CustomPaint and draw this shape but I can't use the image inside this and also I can't control the size for this shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of custom shape creator packages, like:

[flutter_custom_clippers](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers)

[polygon_clipper](https://pub.dev/packages/polygon_clipper)

[clippy_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/clippy_flutter)

Comment: thx I used this package polygon_clipper and it is very helpful